# Exception thrown while publishing a Page when manually created si4t-se-1.2.jar is used

Tags: dxa, si4t, dxa-2.0

I have downloaded the si4t-se-1.2.jar source file from GitHub (https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/tree/develop/storage-extensions) and compiled class files in Eclipse and created a new jar file of the same putting some extra loggers. When I tried to publish a Page after this, I am getting some exceptions as below.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'JPASearchDAOFactory' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:677)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1180)
```

Anyone had this issue before or any insights to what I am missing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK - It looks like some dependencies missing.

Try to troubleshoot by following steps.

1. In the pom.xml add this **maven-dependency-plugin** and rebuild copy the dependencies files from **lib** folder.

```
             <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <excludeGroupIds>com.tridion,org.slf4j,commons-io,commons-codec,commons-logging</excludeGroupIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <excludeGroupIds>com.tridion,org.slf4j,commons-io,commons-codec,commons-logging</excludeGroupIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <excludeGroupIds>com.tridion,org.slf4j,commons-io,commons-codec,commons-logging</excludeGroupIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

**Note:**

If you are planning to install and keep the deployer extension jars under **services/solr-search** folder then ensure to remove the spring boots jars.

2. Ensure your cd_storage configured correctly as expected.
3. Also, ensure your deployer service all the used dependencies jars already exist in the lib folder those versions are should be matched with si4t-se-1.2 pom.xml file.
4. Enable SI4T DEBUG logger in **logback.xml** by adding this following section to see the detailed errors where it's causing.

```
`   <appender name="rollingSI4TExtensionsLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/si4t-extentions.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>${log.encoding}</charset>
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
    </appender>


   <logger name="com.tridion.storage.si4t" level="${log.level}" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingSI4TExtensionsLog" />
   </logger>
```

I hope it helps.